# Directed weighted Graph Data Structure in Java

Tags: java, beginner, graph

I am beginner in Java. I coded **Directed weighted Graph data structure** by myself without anyone's help i want to have some constructive feedback regarding my **program design**, weather my code is perfect or it needs some improvements, Here is my code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @author Rajat
 * Contains 3 classes
 * MapNode - contains info about individual vertex in graph, like nodes connecting to it, its name, edges.
 * MapEdge - class to represent edges between two nodes. it stores distance between two nodes.
 * Graph - Core Graph data structure functionality.
 */
class MapNode{

    private Set<MapEdge> edges;
    private String name;

    public MapNode(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        edges = new HashSet<MapEdge>();    
    }

    void addEdge(MapEdge edge)
    {
        edges.add(edge);
    }
    String getName()
    {
        return new String(this.name);
    }
    Set<MapNode> getNeighbors()
    {
        Set<MapNode> neighbor = new HashSet<MapNode>();
        for(MapEdge edge : edges)
        {
            neighbor.add(edge.getDestination());
        }
        return neighbor;
    }

    Set<MapEdge> getEdges()
    {
        return new HashSet(this.edges);
    }

}
class MapEdge 
{

    private MapNode source, destination;
    private double distance;

    public MapEdge(MapNode source, MapNode destination, double distance) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination= destination;
        this.distance= distance;
    }

    MapNode getSource()
    {
        return this.source;
    }
    MapNode getDestination()
    {
        return this.destination;
    }
    double getDistance()
    {
        return this.distance;
    }
}
public class Graph {

    private int numVertices;
    private Map<MapNode, HashSet<MapEdge>> vertices;

    Graph(){
        numVertices = 0;
        vertices = new HashMap<MapNode, HashSet<MapEdge>>();
    }

    void addEdge(MapNode source, MapNode destination, double distance)
    {
        if(vertices.containsKey(source))
        {
            MapEdge map_edge = new MapEdge(source, destination, distance);
            vertices.get(source).add(map_edge);
            source.addEdge(map_edge);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Source vertex not found..");
        }

    }
    void addVertex(MapNode V)
    {
        if(!vertices.containsKey(V))
        {
            vertices.put(V, new HashSet<MapEdge>());
            System.out.println("Vertex Added");
            ++numVertices;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Vertex already added");
    }

    ArrayList<MapNode> getNeighbor(MapNode vertex)
    {
        return new ArrayList<MapNode>(vertex.getNeighbors());
    }

    // to get distance between verices directly connected to each other
    double getDistance(MapNode source, MapNode destination)
    {
        double distance = 0.0;
        for(MapEdge edge : vertices.get(source))
        {

            if(edge.getDestination() == destination)
            {
                distance = edge.getDistance();
                break;
            }
        }
        return distance;
    }

    // No of vertices in graph
    int numVertices()
    {
        return numVertices;
    }

    void bfs(MapNode source)
    {
        Queue<MapNode> queue = new LinkedList<MapNode>();
        HashSet<MapNode> visited = new HashSet<MapNode>();
        ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList();
        queue.add(source);

        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            MapNode node = queue.poll();
            visited.add(node);
            Set<MapNode> neighbor = node.getNeighbors();
        //    System.out.print("Node " +node.getName()+ "\t ");
            for(MapNode V : neighbor){
             //   System.out.print(V.getName()+" \t");
                if(!visited.contains(V))
                {
                    queue.add(V);
                    visited.add(V);
                    path.add(V.getName());
                }
            }
         //   System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("BFS \t"+path.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Graph graph = new Graph();

        // creating vertex
        MapNode vellore = new MapNode("Vellore");
        MapNode chennai = new MapNode("Chennai");
        MapNode bangalore = new MapNode("Bangalore");
        MapNode mahabalipuram = new MapNode("Mahabalipuram");
        MapNode pondicherry = new MapNode("Pondicherry");
        MapNode yelagiri = new MapNode("Yelagiri");
        MapNode katpadi = new MapNode("Katpadi");
        MapNode kanchipuram = new MapNode("kanchipuram");

        // adding vertex to graph
        graph.addVertex(vellore);
        graph.addVertex(bangalore);
        graph.addVertex(chennai);
        graph.addVertex(mahabalipuram);
        graph.addVertex(pondicherry);
        graph.addVertex(yelagiri);
        graph.addVertex(katpadi);
        graph.addVertex(kanchipuram);

        // conneting edges
        graph.addEdge(chennai, mahabalipuram, 25);
        graph.addEdge(chennai, pondicherry, 300);
        graph.addEdge(pondicherry, mahabalipuram, 500);
        graph.addEdge(chennai, katpadi, 110);
        graph.addEdge(vellore,bangalore, 250);
        graph.addEdge(vellore, chennai, 120);
        graph.addEdge(katpadi, vellore, 15);
        graph.addEdge(bangalore, katpadi, 265);
        graph.addEdge(bangalore, kanchipuram,400 );

        System.out.println("Distance between Chennai to Mahabalipuram "+graph.getDistance(chennai, mahabalipuram));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Naming; Domain Specific Language

Looking at the terms used in this program, we have:

- map node
- map edge
- vertex
- graph

With a bit of care on consistency and simplicity, you could rework these names to:

- graph
- node
- edge

The less terms, and no interchangeable terms, the easier to understand the design.

A minor thing, but I find it odd for an edge to have "distance". `length` seems more natural.

#### Immutable fields

Some of the fields in your design never change.
It's good to make these `final`, to enforce that, and to avoid potential mistakes.

On a related note, this is a pointless operation:

> ```
> String getName()
> {
>     return new String(this.name);
> }
> ```

Strings are immutable in Java, so you can safely return `this.name`.

#### Return when you know the result

The `distance` variable is unnecessary here, and only complicates the implementation:

> ```
> double getDistance(MapNode source, MapNode destination)
> {
>     double distance = 0.0;
>     for(MapEdge edge : vertices.get(source))
>     {
>
>         if(edge.getDestination() == destination)
>         {
>             distance = edge.getDistance();
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>     return distance;
> }
> ```

You can simply return the result immediately when you know it:

```
double getDistance(MapNode source, MapNode destination)
{
    for(MapEdge edge : vertices.get(source))
    {
        if(edge.getDestination() == destination)
        {
            return edge.getDistance();
        }
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

#### Use interfaces in type declarations

Instead of this:

> ```
> private Map<MapNode, HashSet<MapEdge>> vertices;
> ```

You would gain flexibility by using the interface type:

```
private Map<MapNode, Set<MapEdge>> vertices;
```

#### Use the diamond `<>` operator

Instead of this:

> ```
>     vertices = new HashMap<MapNode, HashSet<MapEdge>>();
> ```

You would gain flexibility by using the diamond `<>` operator, supported as of Java 7:

```
    vertices = new HashMap<>();
```

#### Avoid printing

Avoid printing to standard output in methods that are not specifically designed for producing output. Reorganize to move printing functionality in methods designated just for that.

#### Formatting

The coding style doesn't follow the common conventions suggested by modern IDEs. I suggest to edit your program in IntelliJ or Eclipse and use the automatic reformatting feature. It's easier to read code when all developers follow the same conventions.